# Difference between httpd.conf and ssl.conf

Tags: ssl, apache, httpd.conf

What's the difference between `httpd.conf(/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)` and `ssl.conf(/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf)` files?

I'm trying to setup ssl on my site and found these files have similar tokens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`httpd.conf` could divide into separate files, for example, separate the ssl configurations to `ssl.conf`.

So it will also work if you put your ssl configurations in `httpd.conf`, but it is better to put in `ssl.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm a bit confused here, do you have a sample setup where you can show me the difference between these two conf files? Any basic reference would do or a link to explain it in depth would be very much helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Xdazz, Ok finally i understood your reply with the live implementation:). Thanks for your update.